# Interchanging almost surely equal random variables in a conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have random variables $U, V, Y$, where $Y$ is real-valued, and some event $A$ such that, almost surely,
$$
U \, \mathbb{1}_A = V \, \mathbb{1}_A
$$
where $\mathbb{1}_A$ is an indicator function.
Does it follow that
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y \mid \mathbb{1}_A = 1, U] \, \mathbb{P}(A \mid U)
= \mathbb{E}[Y \mid \mathbb{1}_A = 1, V] \, \mathbb{P}(A \mid U)
$$
almost surely?

If everything is discrete, then, provided $\mathbb{P}(U = u) > 0$, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[Y \mid \mathbb{1}_A = 1, U = u] \, \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{1}_A = 1 \mid U = u) %= \left(\sum_{y} y \, \mathbb{P}(Y = y \mid \mathbb{1}_A=1, U=u)\right)\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{1}_A = 1 \mid U = u) \\
= \frac{\sum_y y \, \mathbb{P}(Y = y, \mathbb{1}_A=1, U=u)}{\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{1}_A=1, U=u)} \, \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{1}_A = 1 \mid U = u)\\
= \frac{\sum_y y \, \mathbb{P}(Y = y, \mathbb{1}_A=1, V=u)}{\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{1}_A=1, V=u)} \, \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{1}_A = 1 \mid U = u) \\
= \mathbb{E}[Y \mid A = a, V = u] \, \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{1}_A = 1 \mid U = u).
$$
I am wondering if the same holds true in general, i.e. under the general definition of conditional expectation, with $Y$ an arbitrary (integrable) random variable, and $U$ and $V$ arbitrary measurable functions (subject to the condition above).

Answer (score 1):

You can say that
$$
\mathsf{E}[Y\mid 1_A,U]=\mathsf{E}[Y\mid 1_A,V] \quad\text{a.s. on }A
$$
because for any bounded, measurable function $g$,
\begin{align}
&\mathsf{E}[1_A \mathsf{E}[Y\mid 1_A,U]g(1_A,V)] \\
&\qquad=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[1_A Y\mid 1_A,U]g(1_A,U)] \\
&\qquad=\mathsf{E}[1_AY g(1_A,U)] \\
&\qquad=\mathsf{E}[1_AY g(1_A,V)] \\
&\qquad=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{E}[1_A Y\mid 1_A,V]g(1_A,V)] \\
&\qquad=\mathsf{E}[1_A \mathsf{E}[Y\mid 1_A,V]g(1_A,U)].
\end{align}

Comment: Agreed - however essentially I am wondering whether it is possible to make the same statement, but replacing "a.s. on $A$" with "a.s. on $\{\mathbb{P}(A \mid U) > 0\}$"? The latter is larger than $A$ in the sense that the event $A \cap \{\mathbb{P}(A \mid U) = 0\}$ has measure 0. Is it possible to extend your result to this larger event?

Comment: Then why did you write "$\mathbb{E}[Y \mid \mathbb{1}_A = 1, U] \ldots$"?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[Y \mid \mathbb{1}_A = 1, U]$ is shorthand for $f(1, U)$, where $f(\mathbb{1}_A, U)$ is a version of the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[Y \mid \mathbb{1}_A, U]$. I'm basically evaluating $f$ at a fixed value of $1$ (and the usual random value of $U$) rather than plugging in the random variable $\mathbb{1}_A$ directly.

Comment: For example, when $A=1\{U=0\}$, what is $f(1, 10)$?

Comment: In that case, $f(1, 10)$ is not uniquely defined by the definition of the conditional expectation (since $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{1}_A = 1, U = 10) = 0$). However, we would have $\mathbb{P}(A \mid U)$ almost surely on the event $\{U = 10\}$. Hence the value of $f(1, 10)$ does not matter here: we will still have $\mathbb{E}[Y \mid \mathbb{1}_A = 1, U] \, \mathbb{P}(A \mid U) = \mathbb{E}[Y \mid \mathbb{1}_A = 1, V] \, \mathbb{P}(A \mid U)$ almost surely on this event. My question is basically around trying to extend this to events where $\mathbb{P}(A \mid U)$ is positive.

Comment: Correction - the second sentence of my last comment should start with, "However, we would have $\mathbb{P}(A \mid U) = 0$ almost surely on the event $\{U = 10\}$"